# Short story about 3 historical warriors forced into alien gladiatorial combat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-abduction

About 19 years ago I read a short story featuring, IIRC, a German WW2 officer, a Zulu warrior, and possibly a Roman centurion, who all wake to find they have been abducted and pitted in gladiatorial combat against alien beings.

I seem to recall the officer firing his Luger at some kind of armoured alien and the bullet ricocheting off its carapace, but otherwise I don't remember any specifics.

I believe the story may have been from the 60s or 70s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's funny how these things work out... I was just reading through an old diary on the 20th anniversary of an overseas journey, and in an entry written almost 20 years ago to the day (November 27, 1996) I mentioned reading ["Three Soldiers"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74647) from [*Starry Messenger: The Best of Galileo*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33041). Google reveals the story was written by [D. C. (David) Poyer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?238) in 1978.